# Arguments not present in args

Tags: java

I have a very simple program that output the content of `args`. 
For instance if I launch it with

`$ java main test`
it output

```
> test
```

Now I want it to work with file too, so I create my file `echo test > file1`. If i do a `cat < file1` I will have te right result.

However if I do

`$ java main < file1` I get

```
>
```

(Empty line)

Why is it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<` - tells your command to use file as stdin, it has nothing to do with command arguments.

If you want to append additional argument, use `xargs`: `cat file1 | xargs java main`, or, using `-a` flag: `xargs -a file1 java main`